# I am not sure which discrete distribution method I should use for this probability problem.

Tags: probability

> An oil company drilling estimated that there was a 60% chance of success of finding oil in economic quantities in a particular field. After a first test drilling had been completed the results were favorable. If the probability is 0.3 that the test drilling would give a misleading result then
>
> (1) what is the probability of having positive result?
>
> (2) What is also the probability of finding  oil in economic quantities?

For query 1 is the correct answer 0.7? For (2) is it 0.6? I think this is a bernoulloi problem as there's only one trial but I'm not sure if I am considering the probability properly?

Comment: It sounds a bit misleading, because first the problem states that "the results were favorable", meaning that the test has a positive result (right?). Then, we are asked the probability of getting a positive result - but that already happened! Or am I missing something here? Anyway, I would set
$$
P(\text{Find}) = 0.6 \qquad P(\text{Test correct}) = 0.7
$$
Now, the probability of a positive result can be either from a true positive or from a false positive, or
$$
P(\text{positive result}) = P(\text{Find})P(\text{Test correct}) + P(\text{Not find})P(\text{Test wrong})
$$

Comment: I think the part about favorable results was mentioned with the objective to confuse. I found this problem among similar ones about drilling oil. I took it as that the results were mostly positive with the chance that 0.3 don't meet the standard of success the company was looking for? No idea actually if the answer to the problem is as straightforward as it seems (and I mentioned my thoughts on it with the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_p$ denote a positive result. Also, let $c$ denote the event that the test was correct ans $w$ the event that is was misleading. Finally, let $o$ denotes the event that there is indeed oil.

Query 1:
$$ \begin{align} P(r_p) &= P(o|c) + P(o^C|w) &\implies \\
   P(r_p) &= P(o)\cdot P(c) + P(o^C)\cdot P(w) &\implies \\
   P(r_p) &= 0.6 \cdot 0.7 + 0.4 \cdot 0.3 &\implies \\
   P(r_p) &= 0.54
\end{align}$$

Query 2:
$$ \begin{align}
P(o|r_p) &= \frac{P(r_p|o)\cdot P(o)}{P(r_p)} &\implies \\
P(o|r_p) &= \frac{P(c)\cdot P(o)}{P(r_p)} &\implies \\
P(o|r_p) &= \frac{0.7\cdot 0.6}{0.54} &\implies \\
P(o|r_p) &= \frac{7}{9}
\end{align} $$

Comment: Oh it's a total probability and bayes' theorem problem then! Ha here I was thinking  it had sth to do with bernoulli distribution

Comment: Query 2 is indeed an application of Bayes's rule. Query 1 though isn't exactly LTP.